Dynamic URL for iFrame/ embedded page not working in Builder.io CMS
In builder.io CMS I have a page with a custom code block and a embed media block, because I want to embed a miro.com whiteboard in my page.
If I hardcode the url in either of the blocks it works fine. As soon as I want to set the URL via state.miro_url it doesn't.
For some reason I cannot get the state.miro_url to propagate and be properly rendered.
I have this nextjs code for the miro url:
use client
 import { BuilderComponent } from '@builder.io/react';
 import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
 import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
 import { sseStore } from './SSEstore';
 import { observer } from "mobx-react";
 import { autorun } from "mobx";

 const Context = observer(() => {
    const miro_url = useRef(null); 
     
    ...
    
    useEffect(() => {

        const disposer = autorun(() => {
            if (sseStore.miro_url) {
                miro_url.current = sseStore.miro_url;
                console.log("miro_url.current: " + miro_url.current)
            }

            const storedValue = localStorage.getItem('miro_url');
            if (storedValue) {
                miro_url.current = storedValue;
                console.log("miro_url.current reset from localStorage:" + miro_url.current)
            }
        });

        return () => {
            disposer();
            };
    });

    ...

    return (
        <BuilderComponent
            model='page'
            context={{
                handleWebSocket: handleWebSocket,
                handleAudioContext: handleAudioContext,
                startSession: startUserSession,
            }}
            data={{
                miro_url: miro_url.current
            }}
        />
    );
 });

 export default Context;


I Builder.io CMS I get the url via state.miro_url globally and connect it to the embed media block via Element Data Bindings. For the custom code block I tried injecting the url the same way, did not work. Any ideas?
I have tried hardcoding the url. This works. I have looked in the nginx error logs, nothing there. I have tried various builder.io cms blocks to create the iframe, all with the same result. I have seen it one single time working in my browser on the live site, which indicates to me, that something is wrong with the dynamic rendering of the miro_url parameter. The miro_url is stored in localStorage and sse storage properly, no problems there and rendering the miro board on my page also works when hardcoding the miro_url.
